# Understanding this piece of code (extracting color component from integer)

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that I found when trying to get pixel values from an image, and I don't quite understand it,

```
red = (rgb & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
```

I understand that it's adding 1 to the value if red colour is there, and I think the `0x00ff0000` bit is a hexidecimal value for red, and the `>>` shifts 16 bits to the right.

What is the explanation?

Comment: I prefer `int red = ((rgb >> 16) & 0xff);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is extracting the *red* component from a number that (one would presume) represents a color in aRGB.

First:

```
(rgb & 0x00ff0000)
```

...uses *bitwise and* to zero all bits of `rgb` except those from the byte containing the *red* component (the third most significant byte). Then, that value is shifted right 16 places (using `>> 16`), so that it occupies the right-most byte, the value of which is then assigned to `red`.

For example, assume you've got an `int` representing [vivid cyan](http://www.colorlist.info/colors/vivid-cyan-12faff.html):

```
int color = 0x0012faff;
```

Then, this:

```
int redOnly = color & 0x00ff0000;
System.out.println(redOnly >> 16);
```

Prints:

```
18
```

...which is the decimal value for hex `0x12` (from the *red* position in `color` above).

Similarly, you can get the values of the *green* and *blue* components with the following:

```
int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8; // 250 = 0xfa
int blue = (color & 0x000000ff); // 255 = 0xff
```

Comment: The line : "int redOnly = color & 0x00ffff0000;" should be        "int redOnly = color & 0x00ff0000;" right ?

Comment: @Swagatika - Yep. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Very Very clear explanation one can have. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you start the operation with value `0x00rrggbb` where `r`, `g` and `b` are arbitrary hexadecimal digits. In this case,

```
0x00rrggbb & 0x00ff0000 -> 0x00rr0000 // bitwise-and operation
0x00rr0000 >> 16        -> 0x000000rr // shift-right operation
```

In the end, you've got the value of the red component. You can extract other components using similar operations.

Comment: `0x00rrggbb & 0x00ff0000`, not `&&` ;)

Answer (score 2):

`rgb` holds the red, blue, and green values for the pixel (presumably stored in a 32 bit int).  `rgb & 0x00ff0000` masks off all but the red bits.  The 16 bit shift moves the red bits to the lowest significant positions before they're assigned to the `red` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` is a bitwise operator. For any bit `a` and `b`, `a & b` is 1 if *and only if* both `a` and `b` equals one. For any bit `x`, `x & 1` equals `x` and `x & 0` equals `0`.

Therefore, for any integer i (which is 32 bits in length), `i & 0x00ff0000` will leave only the red component in an RGB:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # the RGB value, and
00000000111111110000000000000000 # 0x00ff0000
-------------------------------- # and'ed together, give
00000000xxxxxxxx0000000000000000 # that
```

There are other ways to extract r, g and b:

```
(rgb >> 16) & 0xff # red
(rgb >> 8) & 0xff  # green
rgb & 0xff         # blue
```